# Java - PTDType1Font Doesn't find the fonts

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

`contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER, 15);`

After that i added the . it shoud come up with many options of fonts, i also imported the library for the function setFont();

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
```

I tried to delete and add the library again, but it didnt work

Comment: Also this is the type of error that it gives me:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 COURIER cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: What version are you using? Hopefully 2.0.28.

Comment: I'm using the 3.0.0 alpha version

Comment: @DanieleZeraschi please add all the info like error and anything else people ask about into the question, not just in comments.

Comment: You're likely a newbie in PDFBox. Use 2.0.28 because 3.0.0 has different classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using PDFBox 2.x code with PDFBox 3.x in a context where these versions differ, see the [PDFBox 3.0 Migration Guide](https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/migration.html#static-instances-for-standard-14-fonts-removed):

> #### Static instances for Standard 14 fonts removed
>
> The static instances of `PDType1Font` for the standard 14 fonts were removed as the underlying `COSDictionary` isn't supposed to be immutable which led to several issues.
>
> A new constructor for `PDType1Font` was introduced to create a standard 14 font. The new Enum `Standard14Fonts.FontName` is the one and only parameter and defines the name of the standard 14 font for which the instance of `PDType1Font` is created for. That instance isn't a singleton anymore and has to be recreated if necessary or cached by the user if suitable.

Answer (score 3):

Use this line of code instead.

```
 contentStream.setFont(new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.COURIER), 15);
```